# PHPform not updating SQL Row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to update sql ROW only using member_id this is my current code.

```
 if ($con = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)) {
    if (mysql_select_db($db_name)) {
        $sql = "UPDATE members set
        ussd_office = '".$ussd_office."',
        ussd_email = '".$ussd_email."',
                    ussd_e1cell4 = '".$ussd_e1cell4."',

        WHERE member_id='$member_id'" ; // This is where my problem lies I presume

if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
            $insertSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            echo $sql;
            print_r($_POST);
            echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);
            echo "mysql err no : " . mysql_errno($con);
```

To get the information my form POST and I place it as follow;

```
 $member_id = $_REQUEST['member_id'];
 $ussd_surname = $_REQUEST['ussd_surname'];
 $member_msisdn = $_REQUEST['member_msisdn'];
 $ussd_office = $_REQUEST['ussd_office'];
```

This is the error I am getting:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>        server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE member_id=''' at line 38mysql 
>        err no : 1064

By looking at the error I presume the `member_id`is not pulled to the `WHERE` part of my string, and the PHP does not know what row to update. How can I correct my code?

Comment: You have an extra comma in your UPDATE, at the end of the line previous to the WHERE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the comma before `WHERE`.

```
"UPDATE members set
        ussd_office = '".$ussd_office."',
        ussd_email = '".$ussd_email."',
                    ussd_e1cell4 = '".$ussd_e1cell4."'
        WHERE member_id='$member_id'"
```

Your variables in the query and variables from REQUEST dont match.

Comment: I have removed the comma now I have no errors but it is not updating the row still

Comment: @MaggieAckermann Does it echo the $sql or it doesn't trip the else condition?

Comment: It doesn't echo anything no errors no nothing when done. It does however just show the blank as if it did update it

Comment: Then try changing `WHERE member_id='$member_id'"` to `WHERE member_id='" . $member_id . "'"` @MaggieAckermann

Comment: I have tried that if i print the sql I get this 

Submit [PHPSESSID] => 648b7516c0d4015c59e37220c7d5593c08efa19b ) Still not updating sql

Comment: Do you have `session_start();` in all your files? @MaggieAckermann

Comment: Ok found the problem typing error on one of my strings thanks guys

Comment: It is not shown in the above code but ussd_e1cell2 = '".$ussd_e1cell2."', is the right one and i had ussd_ecell2 = '".$ussd_e1cell2."', The number 1 was missing

Comment: Thanks, and am glad to hear that you figured it out. You may want to seperate it a bit more like `$ussd_e1_cell2` with an extra underscore, that way it's easier to differentiate. Cheers @MaggieAckermann